# List only child categories a post is in, of a specific parent category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

Either this is harder than it needs to be or I am just not understanding WordPress/PHP very well :( All I want to do is show the child/sub categories of a specific parent category...but only if the post is in those subcategories. Specific example:

I am building a wine reviews website and these are the categories:

- **Brand**

  - Subcategory 1
  - Subcategory 2
  - etc.
- **Region**

  - Subcategory 1
  - Subcategory 2
  - etc.
- **Grape**

  - Subcategory 1
  - Subcategory 2
  - etc.

The parent categories will never change, and every post will have at least 1 subcategory selected under each parent, so in the LOOP I can just list the parents by name. But I am needing to dynamically output the subcategories, something like this:

```
Brand: <?php list_post_subcategories('brand'); ?>
Region: <?php list_post_subcategories('region'); ?>
Grape: <?php list_post_subcategories('grape'); ?>
```

Is there any easy way like this? It seems like this should be a basic function in Wordpress? I've looked at the functions 'get_categories' and 'in_category' but they don't seem to be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $post_child_cat = array();
foreach((get_the_category()) as $cats) {
    $args = array( 'child_of' => $cats->cat_ID );
    $categories = get_categories( $args );
    if( $categories ) foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    echo $category->cat_name; }
} ?>
```

try this

Comment: thanks, but that is just outputting all of the child categories of the post. It's not specific to each parent category.

Comment: if you just want child of a specific category you can do it like `$args = array( 'child_of' =>''category name or id here );` then `$categories = get_categories( $args );` now print `$categories`

Comment: Hmmm...like this? Probably not, I tried it and get no output:

`<?php $post_child_cat = array();
foreach((get_the_category()) as $cats) {
    $args = array( 'child_of' => 'brand' );
    $categories = get_categories( $args );
    if( $categories ) foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    echo $categories; }
} ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I [posted to Wordpress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119486/list-only-child-categories-a-post-is-in-of-a-specific-parent-category) to get more help and [@Milo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4771/milo) gave a great code solution:

```
// get top level terms
$parents = get_terms( 'category', array( 'parent' => 0 ) );
// get post categories
$categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
// output top level cats and their children
foreach( $parents as $parent ):
// output parent name and link
echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $parent ) . '">' . $parent->name . '</a>: ';
// initialize array to hold child links
$links = array();
foreach( $categories as $category ):
    if( $parent->term_id == $category->parent ):
        // put link in array
        $links[] = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $category ) . '">' . $category->name .      '</a>';
    endif;
endforeach;
// join and output links with separator
echo join( ', ', $links );
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` so you can return only the categories that you want. For example:

```
array_map( function( $cat ) {
        if ( $cat->parent != 0 ) {
            return $cat;
        }
     },
     get_the_category()
);
```